# Fluentd to Kafka on Kubernetes connection Issues

Tags: docker, kubernetes, logging, apache-kafka, fluentd

I'm having issues connecting Fluentd to Kafka for a centralized logging  PoC I'm working on.

I'm currently using the following configuration:

- Minikube
- Fluentd
- `fluent/fluentd-kubernetes-daemonset:v1.14.3-debian-kafka2-1.0` (docker)

  - Configuration: I have the `FLUENT_KAFKA2_BROKERS=<INTERNAL KAFKA BOOTSTRAP IP>:9092` and `FLUENT_KAFKA2_DEFAULT_TOPIC=logs` env set in my yaml for fluentd daemonset.
- Kafka

I was sort of expecting to see the logs appear in a Kafka consumer running against the same broker listening on the "logs" topic. No dice.

Could anyone recommend next steps for troubleshooting and or a good reference? I've done a good bit of searching and have only found a few people posting about setting up with the fluentd-kafka plugin. Also would it make sense for me to explore Fluent Bit Kafka setup as an alternative?

Comment: Have you checked the logs for fluentd container on Kubernetes side? Is it working correctly?

Comment: Yes the logs on Kubernetes / Fluentd are all working correctly. I actually had the whole thing working against ELK directly and could view logs in Kibana. Looking to shoot the same logs to Kafka for an different integration project.

Answer (score 0):

In general, to configure forwarding of log events to Kafka topic you would definitely need to use output plugins for Fluentd.

Fluentd delivers [fluent-plugin-kafka](https://github.com/fluent/fluent-plugin-kafka) plugin,  as specified in [Fluentd docs](https://docs.fluentd.org/v/0.12/output/kafka), for both input and output use cases. For output case, this plugin has Kafka Producer functions to publishes messages into topics.  [kafka-connect-fluentd](https://github.com/fluent/kafka-connect-fluentd) plugin can also be used as an alternative.

[Fluent Bit](https://fluentbit.io/)  - being the sub-project of Fluentd - a good lightweight alternative for Fluentd, but which one to use depends on your particular use case.
Fluent Bit has limited amount of filtering options, it is not as pluggable and flexible as Fluentd. The later has more configuration options and filters, it can be integrated with a much larger amount of input and output sources. It is essentially designed to deal with heavy throughput — aggregating from multiple inputs, processing data and routing to different outputs. More on comparison  [here](https://docs.fluentbit.io/manual/about/fluentd-and-fluent-bit)  and [here](https://logz.io/blog/fluentd-vs-fluent-bit/#:%7E:text=Fluent%20Bit%20is%20also%20extensible,CPU%2C%20memory%2C%20and%20disk.&text=The%20Kubernetes%20Fluent%20Bit%20filter,ID%2C%20annotations%2C%20and%20labels.).